# How can I find all the handlers for a "RaisePropertyChanged" call?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property that looks similar to this:

```
    private ISomething currentSomething;
    public ISomething CurrentSomething
    {
        get { return currentSomething; }
        set
        {
            if (!object.Equals(currentSomething, value))
            {
                currentSomething = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentSomething);
            }
        }
    }
```

When the setter gets called, the value is correctly transfered to the `currentSomething` field.  However, after the `RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentSomething);` line, one of the lists in the currentSomething field has a two of the items removed.

It seems clear to me that something in my code is subscribed to the event of this property changing (and is pruning the list I need left alone).  However, I can't seem to find this handler.

**Is there an way to find all subscribers to a RaisePropertyChanged event?**

**UPDATE:**
I figured out what was up with my object.  It was bound to a control that had a view model that was doing stuff to it.  I am going to leave the question open in case someone has a good answer, but I am no longer stuck.

Comment: Assuming there are no *explicit* listeners, I would do a global search for "CurrentSomething" and see what is bound to it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - I tried that.  No luck.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to just "find" all the listeners (since most will be in the framework) but I'm glad you aren't stuck anymore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GetInvocationList() method on the event. If you have a PropertyChanged event on the myObject (of type MyClass) instance then you can get the subscribers like this:

```
        var methodInfo = typeof (MyClass.PropertyChangedDelegate).GetMethod("GetInvocationList");
        var p = myObject.GetType().GetField("PropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(myObject);
        var subscriberDelegates = (Delegate[])methodInfo.Invoke(p, null);
        object[] subscriberObjects = subscriberDelegates.Select(sub => sub.Target).ToArray();
```

This will work even outside the class that defines the event.

Comment: Is this doable from outside of the class defining the event?